# How to create a timer then notify the user that its finish

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

I have a website and I want to create a timer for a user like. If they can't click the submit button within 30 seconds it will notify the user that it is pass 30 seconds and your still not clicking the button something like that. I've tried searching for an alarm clock as an example for php yet I can't find anything. Hope it can be done using php or js. Thank you for your replies

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: `for php` - wrong language for client side timer

Comment: you can do this by using jQuery

Comment: If you **seriously** want to do this using PHP, you can have a timer server side and use websockets/sse/long polling to check if the timer is up and show an alert client side. All would require js code anyway. Not to mention that this is **highly convoluted and unnecessary**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will help you.

```js
var userSubmit = false;
var timeout;
if (!userSubmit) {
   timeout = setTimeout( function(){ 
      alert("Timer Done"); 
   }, 3000);
}
function alertSubmit() {
 userSubmit = true;
 clearTimeout(timeout);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="alertSubmit()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: @JenelHapitana You Welcome

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in JavaScript

```
setTimeout( function(){ 
    alert("Timer Done"); 
}, 30000);
```

30000 milliseconds is 30 seconds

Answer (score 0):

** You can use setTimeout in JavaScript.**

```js
function myFunction() {
    setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <p>Click the button to wait 3 seconds, then alert "Hello".</p>

        <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That does not appear to be php code. That is JavaScript